# Windows 7 mobile app development

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it the right time to start a long duration project for windows 7 mobile ? as silverlight and flash are dying away ... and HTML 5 which would be the future platform ... or should i wait for some more time for windows 7  to extend support HTML 5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 HTML 5 support is not yet good enough. So if you want to create a application for WP7 then you would need to use Silverlight.

The HTML 5 support will be better in WP8 but it's not yet sure when it will be released and how good the support will be.

Comment: "not yet good enough" compared to what? HTML5 isn't even a standard for the next couple of years and the current Windows Phone 7 is supporting the IE9 rendering engine. Frameworks like PhoneGap for HTML5-Mobile-Apps are already compiling for the Windows Phone platform. Also Silverlight development isn't dying per-se but only as a web-plugin. It's still very popular for .NET intranet and the main framework for most Windows Phone applications (beside XNA).

Comment: Current HTML5 applications compared to Silverlight Applications. It's very hard to make HTML5 application look and feel as good as Silverlight application.